# How to get only "direct" children of a parent?

Tags: jquery, html

Having html structure like this:

```
<div id="parent1" class="parent">
   <div class="child">1<div/>
   <div>
       <div class="child">2</div>
   </div>

   <div id="parent2" class="parent">
      <div class="child">3</div>
      <div>
         <div class="child">4</div>
      </div>
      <div id="parent3" class="parent">
         <div class="child">5</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How could I write a selector that returns only the direct children of a specified parent?
So for parent2 I want to get child 3 and child 4 but not child 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, and I think the selector will be based on your actual html, but I think this should work for your specific example:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQ4C/

```
$('.parent .child:not(".parent .parent .child")').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for my original question. But it is not exactly what I want. I want it to work on any level of parent tree not only for root level.

Answer (score 0):

For `jQuery`, [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will traverse a single level of the `DOM`.

```
$('.parent').children('.child').each(function() {

    // do something with each of the direct decedents

});
```

In your case, this will mean that you would return the "first" `.child` and the "third" `.child` entries, reading from top-to-bottom in your `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** http://jsfiddle.net/9sSqE/

or could use `closest` http://api.jquery.com/closest/ **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/T26Sa/

Hope this fits your needs `:)`

**code**

```
$('.parent').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.child').html('HULK ---- Found');
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score -4):

CSS is easy

```
.parent > .child
```

[**http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

Comment: This would also grab the third child, which is _not_ what the question asks.

Comment: Perhaps it's the term 'more deep' (as in deeper nested) when what was actually meant was 'lower' that threw me off. Plus the messed up HTML :)